# Stop Bootstrap 5 input from resizing to height of CSS grid cell

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I've got some Bootstrap 5 markup below.

The first example is wrong. I do not want the Bootstrap input to be the same height as the grid cell.

The second example is correct BUT I do not want to use a wrapper div. Is there any way to get the same result without using a wrapper div?

PS: I am intentionally not using the Bootstrap grid system - I want to use CSS grid.

```css
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.grid-cell {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h4>This is wrong</h4>
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="grid-cell"></div>
  <input class="form-control">
</div>

<hr>

<h4>This is correct but I do not want a wrapper div</h4>
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="grid-cell"></div>
  <div class="I-DONT-WANT-THIS-WRAPPER-DIV">
    <input class="form-control">
  <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `align-items: start` to `.my-grid`, like below;

```css
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  align-items: start;
}

.grid-cell {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h4>This is wrong</h4>
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="grid-cell"></div>
  <input class="form-control">
</div>

<hr>

<h4>This is correct but I do not want a wrapper div</h4>
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="grid-cell"></div>
  <div class="I-DONT-WANT-THIS-WRAPPER-DIV">
    <input class="form-control">
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I actually just wanted align-self: center but u got me looking in the right place :)